# +1 (Google Plus One) in Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: html, cordova, google-plus-one

I'm building a game in HTML using Cordova/Phonegap (well, specifically https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps) and I'm looking to add a +1 (google plus one) button for my app's play store page, and have it actually work.

I can currently get it to add the button, and show the current number of +1's, but when you tap it, it tries to open another window then returns the the game, without having added the +1 (I check my +1's page to make sure it wasn't working, but failing to update)

I'm using the web way to add the button, but would prefer a cordova plugin.

Any help is awesome,
Cheers!

Comment: Hi @shane-gadsby, have you solved this problem?
I have a very similar problem: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-plus-1-button-inside-app/43806

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find a solution before the deadline I had; and have yet to look back into it. I strongly suspect that it may be possible, but have no evidence that it does-  sorry!

Comment: Ok... :( I will look into it a bit more, maybe open another question on stackoverflow and offer a bounty....

Comment: Hey Shane!
I'm not having much luck with this.... There's a bounty open if you want to try.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541290/how-to-place-a-google-plus-1-button-inside-cordova-ionic-app

Comment: JFYI, I created a plugin. You have the details on Rodrigo's question http://stackoverflow.com/a/35749627/1351469

Comment: @jcesarmobile: legend! Thanks for making it!