# How to place a Google Plus +1 button inside cordova/ionic app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, webview, ionic-framework, google-plus

I've added a +1 button in my app:
[image: +1 in Cordova/Ionic]

I've used this code:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall" data-href="GOOGLE PLAY STORE LINK TO MY APP"></div>
```

and

```
(function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
```

I've also allowed the api:

index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://apis.google.com">
```

config.xml:

```
<allow-navigation href="https://apis.google.com" />
```

**The problem:**
This works on the browser (`ionic serve`) but It doesn't work on the app...
When I click nothing happens... (no errors...)

Anyway I can make this work on the app? (`ionic run`)

More information/debug info:

1. If I've clicked the +1 button on the web it doesn't show me the red button on the app (Read means I've already shared that link)(It doesn't know who I am..)
2. I don't want to make a login/signup, just a +1 button...

If I add:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

in config.xml, it asks me to login when I click the +1 button: (It shouldn't)
[image]

This means the +1 button doesn't work because is "in an anonymous browser", not authenticated with the OS...

I also created a demo pure Android app following this instructions: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend
It works perfectly... (I can +1 the link...)

My possibilites:

1. Some way to make a native Android view with the +1 button appear on the webview.
2. Make a fake +1 button and when it's clicked it calls a plugin that makes some king of request/click on the real +1 button....
3. **Any suggestion on how to do it?**

Are any of these two possibilities possible?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to handle the login, you can build a plugin to add a native `PlusOneButton`.
I'm working on it right now, I'll try to release it this afternoon, but as moderators don't like "link only asnwers" I'll explain here how to build the plugin, and I'll add the link once I finish developing it.

First of all, read the [guide about how to build a cordova plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html), I'm not going to enter into that level of detail.

Your CordovaPlugin subclass will need this variables:

```
private PlusOneButton mPlusOneButton;
private String URL;
```

Your execute method should be like this:

```
public boolean execute(String action, final JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if (action.equals("show")) {//show is the name of the method you call from javascript
        URL = "http://www.phonegap.es";//you should pick it from the plugin params
        mPlusOneButton =  new PlusOneButton(cordova.getActivity());
        mPlusOneButton.initialize(URL, null);

        //you have to run this part making sure you run it on the UI Thread
        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                cordova.getActivity().addContentView(mPlusOneButton,new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                //position the button wherever you want, you should pick the values from the plugin params
                mPlusOneButton.setX(300);
                mPlusOneButton.setY(300);

            }
        });

    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Finally add the `onResume` method to keep the button status up to date.

```
@Override
public void onResume(boolean multitasking) {
    super.onResume(multitasking);
    mPlusOneButton.initialize(URL, null);
}
```

The plugin will have to add the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus` dependency

You can do that adding this line to the plugin.xml

```
<framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:+" />
```

EDIT: The plugin is ready https://github.com/jcesarmobile/plusOneButtonPlugin

To install it

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/jcesarmobile/plusOneButtonPlugin
```

To use it:

```
var params = {};
params.url = "http://www.example.com";
params.position = {x:100,y:100};
plusOneButton.show(params);
```

Or

```
plusOneButton.show("http://www.example.com");
```

Comment: The only "problem" now is the x,y  thing.... If I make any progress I will contribute to the plugin repo!
Do you have any good ideia on how to solve that? I was thinking of placing a empty div where I want it and use the "coordinates" from it....

Comment: It's not the best solution but it should work (theoretically), and this also confirms we can show a native view appear, as I speculated in my original question...

Comment: Yeah, that should work. I can add a method to set the x and y whenever you want in case you want to reposition on phone rotation

Comment: My particular app is locked to portrait but that would be a nice feature for the future!

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is that the user isn't logged in with their Google account inside the cordova browser, so obviously, you see a login prompt when clicking the +1 button.

I understand you want to access the global Google account connected to the user's phone/OS and use this one inside your app. First, your app needs credentials to access this data, then those need to be accessible from within the cordova browser. There's [this plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) which does that for you.

In your initialization code, you can then call `window.plugins.googleplus.login(...)`, which will prompt the user for confirmation (if necessary) and log in.

Make sure that the +1 button is initialized after logging in, so the state is indicated correctly. For instance (assuming you're using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  loginToGoogle();
  initPlusOneButton();
}

function loginToGoogle() { ... }

function initPlusOneButton() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to login the user (as I pointed out before) and I had seen that plugin, it didn't seem to work as I wanted but I will give it a try later....

Comment: I don't understand. The +1 button always requires the user to be logged in. The reason it's working in your desktop browser is that you're already logged in. Try the same in a private/incognito window and you'll see a login prompt.

Comment: Yes, but a normal Android app doesn't need to do that... But I understand that it's like if the user was in incognito/private mode....
(I've not tried the plugin yet...)

Comment: I'm not being able to set up this plugin.... The "webApiKey" is killing me.... I tried all kinds of keys.... Always says "no valid token" or other problem...

Comment: You need to get one from the Google Developers Console as described [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth).

Comment: Following those instructions I got it showing the login thing: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/master/screenshots/Android2.png and trying to use the "trySilentLogin" didn't work with the exact same webapikey.... I've not yet allowed it to login.... I don't want to see that login popup.... a normal Android app doesn't show it.... neither the Google Chrome app.... (in websites....)

Comment: That's because there's a new (third-party) app accessing the user's information, so the user needs to confirm the first time for security and transparency reasons; there is no way to avoid this. From then on, [silentSignIn will work without any further prompt](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in). Chrome and other apps have probably been approved earlier for your account - not necessarily on your phone, since this only needs to be done once globally.

Comment: Yheaa but native android  apps don't do it, probably because the "OS" is already authenticated with my account.... I know that we can put a webview anywhere inside an android app, can we put and android view inside an webview?

Comment: Not inside, but over it

Comment: @jcesarmobile That would be nice if I could position it always in the same place.... (In the middle of two buttons...)